# Disable time selection before exact current time?

Tags: javascript, web, time

I want to enable **only** future time selection in my app. I want to disable all the days before today (I managed to do that) and all the times before now. I cannot use the timestamp directly, since it disables today as well. This is how my code looks:

```
$givenValue = '111122233334444'; //any given timestamp

//I need to know the exact condition here
if($givenValue < Date.now()) {
    //Disable selection
}
```

This disables all the past days, including today. I want today to be enabled but the time selection should be after exact current time only.

Comment: Have a look into this http://plnkr.co/edit/gGAU0L?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! But I am not using that directive, its a different one. Ignore the directive, I just want a way to compare time in such a way that I can enable only future times.

Comment: You want  that in Angular or Jquery

Comment: General time comparison. Just assume I want to display a message that only future time selection is allowed.